# append html inside directive with scope values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i am trying to make a pie chart directive and i use the highcharts one but i also want to add another line of text that sais for example '60%' or so. So far i tried this

```
app.directive('pieGraph', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'C',
    scope: {
      value: '@',
      color: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem) {
      elem.highcharts({
        chart: {
          type: 'pie',
          backgroundColor: null
        },
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            shadow: true
          }
        },
        legend: {
          enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
          enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
          name: '',
          data: [
            {
              name: 'a',
              y: parseInt(scope.value, 10),
              color: scope.color
            },
            {
              name: 'b',
              y: (100 - parseInt(scope.value, 10)),
              color: '#ffffff'
            }
          ],
          size: '100%',
          innerSize: '90%',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }]
      });

      var graph = angular.element('<span class="pie-graph-value">{{scope.value}}<sup>%</sup></span>');
      $compile(graph)(scope);
      elem.append(graph);
    }
  };
});
```

but this issue is that the last  that i applied, sais only % instead the value and percent symbol. Is there something wrong i did on the compile stuff on the end ?

Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `{{value}}` or write your element as `'<span class="pie-graph-value">' + scope.value + '<sup>%</sup></span>'` (note the latter will not update later since the value is only calculated once when appending the element).
This element will be rendered so the reference to `scope` is implicit.

Comment: oh my god man, i can't believe i wrote scope inside the html :) thank you so much mate, this answer helped me ALOT !